# Cassandra (Datastax v3.5) using Stratio Lucene Index plugin - Windows

Tags: cassandra, lucene, datastax, stratio, cassandra-lucene-index

I'm trying to look at using the Stratios Lucene index plugin (on Windows)installation of Cassandra (Datastax v3.5) but can't get Cassandra to recognize it.

I'm aware that you must use the corresponding version to Cassandra and have tried with 3.0.5 & 3.5 but both with the same results. The service is stopped, the index .jar file is copied to the lib directory & then the service is restarted. Then using CQLSH, I can create the relevant keyspace & table (as described in the Stratio documentation) but when attempting to create the index it fails with the following message:

Query invalid because of configuration issue: message="Unable to find custom indexer class 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'"

https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/tree/branch-3.5

Does anyone have any idea how to get this implemented & working?
Is there a central forum or a point of contact for Stratios Lucene index support?

Comment: Have got the same issue and exactly the same environment. Support seems to be there: https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues

Answer (score 0):

This resource https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues/118#issuecomment-211796434 suggests that only open source Apache Cassandra is officially supported by this plugin. It might work with DSE, might not. I checked 3.5.0 version works on Linux with Apache Cassandra but does not work on Windows with DSE :( According to Datastax docs, it should support custom secondary indexes. So, it might be the plugin does not run on Windows?